# How to find out which promise resolved with Promise.any?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I was doing some batch IO with `Promise.all`, but eventually I hit a limit of open files by creating too many IO promises at once. So instead, I made an utility, that will run those promises in batches of 50 at most.

One solution is to divide the tasks in batches of fifty, and then do `Promise.all` on each batch. But smarter solution would be to cycle the promises as they resolve using `Promise.any`. Problem is, `Promise.any` only returns the result, and not which promise returned.

How to find out which resolved so that I can replace it in the batch with new unresolved one?

Comment: Instead of keeping references to specific promises, you can also just keep a count of how many are running. If *any* completes, add a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no native way to find the `Promise` that was completed.

But I thought of a workaround. Basically, I assigned each `Promise` an id then I destructure the return value of the `Promise` and log out the id and result

```js
const Promise4 = fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=1&offset=20').then(response => response.json()).then(result => ({
  id: 4,
  result
}));
const Promise1 = fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=1&offset=12').then(response => response.json()).then(result => ({
  id: 1,
  result
}));
const Promise2 = fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=1&offset=5').then(response => response.json()).then(result => ({
  id: 2,
  result
}));
const Promise3 = fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=1&offset=23').then(response => response.json()).then(result => ({
  id: 3,
  result
}));


Promise.any([Promise1, Promise2, Promise3, Promise4]).then(({
  id,
  result
}) => console.log(`Promise${id} returned`, result.results[0].name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a.mola's answer, but keeping the promise index tracking a little  closer to the `Promise.any` call, we could `map` over the input array to add a tag and destructure to retrieve it:

```js
const promises = [
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("p0value"), 1000)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("p1value"), 500))
];

const promiseAnyIndexed = pp => Promise.any(pp.map((p,i)=>p.then(res=>[res,i])));

const [res, i] = await promiseAnyIndexed(promises);

console.log(res,i);    // p1value 1
```